# How do I successfully install the LecoS plug-in for QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I have been trying to follow the instructions given [here](http://conservationecology.wordpress.com/lecos-land-cover-statistics/#comment-394), but repeatedly get an error message pop-up titled "Mount" stating Access is Denied.

Does anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little quick-and-dirty tutorial to assist you. This is how i installed LecoS on Windows XP for QGIS 1.8.

Download the file [here](http://conservationecology.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/24072013_howtoinstallscipyforqgis.pdf).

I can not help you for MacOS systems. Scipy should be available here as well, but i do not own a Mac for testing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the LecoS [install page](http://conservationecology.wordpress.com/lecos-land-cover-statistics/), you need to install python-scipy, python-numpy, python-imaging which you're supposed to be able to install via the OSGEO4W Installer (which is python-PIL, don't looking for python-imaging).

I ran into some errors with the installer, so it didn't actually work when I tried, but I haven't had time to go back and figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Yes I reached this stage and selected the correct pythons, but the error message appeared just before the installation completed.

Comment: Has anyone had any success installing this plug-in? I have tried on 2 different machines now, but without success.